# S&P 500 P/E percentile

Tags: research, market-data

I am researching the past five year return for the securities in the top and bottom 10 percentile of the S&P 500 on date 5 years ago.  I used Bloomberg to get this data.  When I searched for the top 10 percent of stocks based on P/E ratio in the S&P 500 5 years ago, my searched returned 48 stocks.  Why was it 48 instead of 50?

Comment: Does Bloomberg account for the changing composition of the S&P500?

Comment: Yes, but I did not accoutnt for changing index composition in my analysis.  I simply took the top 10 percentile of the S&P 500 by P/E ratio on 5/27/07 and calculated the 5 year return. Bloomberg returned 48 stocks.  That was wierd because I was expecting 50.

Comment: What do you mean Bloomberg accounted for it, but you didn't. If you select the S&P500 composition today and then get their P/E on 5/27/2007 and calculate 5 year return of them, then some of the stocks that are in the S&P500 today may not have existed five years ago (like a spin-off). Alternately, if you took the S&P500 as it existed on 5/27/2007, sorted by top percentile and calculated the return, then companies like Lehman may no longer exist and not have five year returns.

Comment: Yes I agree, but I was wondering when I first sorted the S&P 500 index  for year 2007 the top 10 percentile of companies based on P/E ratio returned only 48 stocks to begin with?

Comment: If you ask for the top 100% of stocks, do you get the full 500? What John is saying is that calculating returns over a period of time requires that the stocks be around during that entire period. So Lehman Brothers and Bear Stearns don't qualify. Also, the S&P 500 could have changed their list of index constituents, again as John said.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible for many reasons; one of which was explained by John. Another reason could be what you used for your P/E multiple. If it was a direct field providing you the ratio, then there is a possibility that a couple of those stocks had a negative EPS that period. Bloomberg (and many similar data vendors) do not calculate a ratio if the denominator is negative. A workaround to this is to have the P/E calculated yourself by looking at Price and EPS individually.